# Filter return results on Get-SPUser?

Tags: powershell

Having an SharePoint 2010 installation I try to filter the return result of `Get-SPUser` but I don't see any possible ways to get a single user or filtered users back.

```
Get-SPUser -Web https://intranet.mysite.com -Limit '30'
```

Is it possible to use another Get-User method to return only those SPUsers who match search criterion, such as `AD\an*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Get-SPUser -web https://intranet.mysite.com | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like "*AD\an*"}
```

For more info on Where-Object: [Using the Where-Object Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx)

Comment: Great! It even works with -Limit ALL

Answer (score 0):

```
$user=Get-SPUser -Web "you site url" -Limit "All"|Where-Object{$_.Name -match ("sptestuser")}
Write-Host ("User id:"+$user.ID+"  Display name:"+$user.DisplayName+"  Login name:"+$user.LoginName)
```

The above script get the user from the site with u`ser name:sptestuser`

Comment: Robert's code helped me with a p.i.t.a problem i had where i couldn't tell if my SP 2013 farm knew about certain User Groups.  Plugged in my info and it tole me the id and other info i needed to proceed with powershell. thanks